# MS Visual C++ 2008 Express cannot find path

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to do something basic

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  
int main()  
{  
    cout << "Hello, World!";  
    return 0;  
}
```

After using F7 I get

> 1>mt.exe : general error c10100b1: Failed to load file "..\Debug\helloworld.exe". The system cannot find the path specified.

So it cant find the file that it'll eventually create?

What gives?

Comment: Are you sure that the build succeeded?

Comment: @ChrisF: why did you add the dots in the include statement?

Comment: @orsogufo - if I did it wasn't intentional. I was concerned about the lack of code after the #include statement so I edited the question to change the formatting from "blockquote" to "code". The dots were already there.

Comment: @orsogufo - looking at the edit history I think we edited the post at the same time & I stomped on your edits. I did think about removing the dots, but thought they might be significant.

Answer (score 1):

mt.exe is the manifest tool. The manifest tool shouldnt run if there is a build error. I dont think you will see mt.exe run if there is a build error. Go to your solution file, under the manifest tab, check if the path's in the settings are not hard coded to some wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <.iostream.>
```

Did your build really succeed? The above line looks suspicious - I'd have expected to see (note the missing periods):

```
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: Yes, the periods aren't supposed to be there, but thanks to blockquote not using them the iostream disappears.

I doubt the build succeeded.